# How to send bulk messages using wp mail function?

Tags: wp-mail

I was working in custom plugin development. I have created customer table in woocommerce and create form to reminder customer for new offers. I am using wp mail function to send multiple email to customer but its works with single customer mail.

here its my code

```
<form class="formpopup" action="#" method="post">
                            <div>
                            <label>To</label><input id="customer_to_mail" type="text" class="modalform" style="width: 70%;" value="" name="customer_to_mail" required></div><br>
                            <div><label>Subject</label><input class="modalform" style="width: 70%;" type="text" name="customer_subject" required></div><br>
                            <div class="descr"><label>Description</label><textarea class="modalform" style="width: 70%; height: 150px;" name="customer_description" required></textarea></div><br>
                            <input style="margin: 20px auto; display: flex;" type="submit" name="send-mail" value="Send Email">
                            <?php
                            $to = array($_POST['customer_to_mail']); //sendto@example.com
                                    $subject = $_POST['customer_subject'];
                                    $body = $_POST['customer_description'];
                                    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

                                    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers ); ?>
                        </form>
```

And Js code to automatic give customer email in to field

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.emlchk').click(function() {
       
        var selectedEmailAddress = '';

                jQuery('.emlchk:checked').each(function() {    // $(':checkbox:checked')
                    jQuery('.checkbox_value').text(this.value + ' ');   

                     var emailAdd = jQuery("#EmailAddressTD_"+this.value+"").text();

                     selectedEmailAddress = ""+selectedEmailAddress+""+emailAdd+"";

                });
         jQuery("#customer_to_mail").val(selectedEmailAddress);

    });
});
```

Comment: I don't recommend sending bulk emails directly from webhosts, they'll likely end up in the spam folder. If you need to bulk mail then it's best to use a service that can handle it properly. This is why most mailing list plugins use Mailchimp and other services rather than sending the emails directly. Your host might not like you doing it either

Comment: I'd also be very careful that what you've put in your question is technically allowing anybody to email anybody else without validation, I could use that form to send email to anybody I want pretending to be you and your site.

Comment: No email is sent only from the backend so only the owner is able to send emails.